# Implement the max operator in RPN (postfix) calculator

Tags: postfix-notation

I try to implement a RPN (postfix) calculator but a requirement for this is use the MAX operator such in the following examples

```
input: 5 2 "MAX" 2 1 "MAX" "*"
output: 10

input: 8 7 4 "MAX" 2 2 "+" "-"
output: 4

input: 3, 7, 5, "MAX", 1, 9, 7, "MAX", "MAX", "SQRT"
output: 3

input: 3, 5, 4, "MAX", "*"
output: 15
```

I use a stack to evaluate with binary operators and unary operator SQRT but I don't know how to implement the MAX operator given that this has no a unique number or operands.

Comment: Are you given this input specification, or is that something you can change? The easiest would be to push the number of args to max as the last argument. Otherwise, you may try to figure it out by using a lookahead, but that would not work for MAX followed by MAX.

Comment: About use a new argument, it is not an option, the only input is a RNP expresion. These are the test for the implementation, the MAX followed by MAX is such as: max(max(3, 7, 5), max(1, 9, 7)) that is 9.

Comment: The problem is at the last one, where you have to use only two of the three args in the stack to compute max. That is, you need a lookahead to figure out there is a `*`, and reserve one argument for that.

Comment: However, if you have `1 2 3 4 5 6 MAX * MAX` as input, then there is no way to find out how many numbers should go to the first MAX, and how many to the second.

Comment: This isn't `python` *or* `Go`.  Should this instead be tagged `postfix-notation`?

Comment: RPN, not RNP. Reverse Polish Notation.